# How to display entries filtered from more than one category

Tags: categories, array, params, string, querystring

I want to try to learn how I can filter entries by multiple categories. I realise similar questions have been asked in the past, but all the answers are for specific use cases. All I want to do is filter entries by categories from more than one group. I've found code to set up a form that returns the URL with a string, but I understand that the string needs to be converted into an array. That's the part I can't work out how to do.
So the form is like this:

```
        {# Get the relevant entries #}
    {% set categoryQuery = craft.app.request.getParam('category') %}
    {% set categories = craft.categories.group('candidate').slug(categoryQuery) %}

    {# Set the search parameters #} 
    {% set searchParams = {
        relatedTo: categories,
        section: 'candidate'
    } %}

    {# Get the relevant entries #}
    {% set relevantEntries = craft.entries(searchParams) %}

    <form action="{{ craft.app.request.absoluteUrl }}">

        <p>Eye colour</p>

        {% for category in craft.categories.group('eyeColour').all() %}
            <input id="{{category.slug}}" type="checkbox" name="category[]"  value="{{ category.slug }}" {{ category.slug in categoryQuery or categoryQuery == null  ? 'checked'}}>
            <label for="{{ category.slug }}" >{{ category.title }}</label>
        {% endfor %}

        <p>Hair colour</p>

        {% for category in craft.categories.group('hairColour').all() %}
            <input id="{{category.slug}}" type="checkbox" name="category[]"  value="{{ category.slug }}" {{ category.slug in categoryQuery or categoryQuery == null  ? 'checked'}}>
            <label for="{{ category.slug }}" >{{ category.title }}</label>
        {% endfor %}

        <p><button type="submit">
                Search
        </button></p>               

    </form>
```

Which gives me a URL like this

```
/?category%5B%5D=blue&category%5B%5D=black
```

Comment: What do you get if you do this: {{ dump(categoryQuery) }} ?

Comment: No result I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I've got for filtering news by author and by category. You might be able to re-work it for your needs?

From a page URL being: `http://project.com/news?&cat=CATEGORY&author=NAME`

```
{% set query = {} %}

{% set categoryParam = craft.app.request.getParam('cat') %}
{% set authorParam = craft.app.request.getParam('author') %}

{% set category = craft.categories.slug(categoryParam) %}
{% set author = craft.entries.section('team').slug(authorParam).first() %}

{% if category %}
    {% set query = query|merge(category) %}
{% endif %}

{% if author %}
    {% set query = query|merge(author) %}
{% endif %}

{% if categoryParam and authorParam %}

    {% set results = targetEntries.relatedTo(['and',
            { targetElement: category },
            { targetElement: author }
        ]
    ).orderBy('postDate desc') %}

    {% set noResultsMessage = "Sorry, there are no articles by " ~ author.title ~ " in that category. Try changing your filters." %}

{% elseif categoryParam %}

    {% set results = targetEntries.relatedTo(category).orderBy('postDate desc') %}
    {% set noResultsMessage = "Sorry, there are no articles in that category. Try filtering by a different category." %}

{% elseif authorParam %}

    {% set results = targetEntries.relatedTo(author).orderBy('postDate desc') %}
    {% set noResultsMessage = "Sorry, there are no articles by " ~ author.title ~ ". Try filtering by someone else." %}

{% else %}

    {% set results = targetEntries.orderBy('postDate desc') %}

{% endif %}
```

It was written a long time ago, so I'm seeing some places where I can streamline it, but this works for me filtering by two fields. I think the key part for your requirements is:

```
{% set results = targetEntries.relatedTo(['and',
    { targetElement: category },
    { targetElement: author }
]).orderBy('postDate desc') %}
```

Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Cheers I'll give it a go and see what I get

Comment: No worries, I hope it leads you down the right path at least. 